# Accessing first list element contents in BeautifulSoup or Selenium with regex

Tags: python, regex, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm using Selenium to search for a laptop. I want to print out only the graphics card to the console. Here's my code so far:

```py
search_field = browser.find_element_by_id('main-search')
search_field.send_keys("Asus TUF Gaming A17 FA706QM 17,3")
search_field.submit()
print("Search Bar Entered")
sleep(3)

page_source = browser.page_source
page_soup = soup(page_source,'html.parser')
specs = page_soup.find("ul",{"class":"specs"})
print(specs)
p = re.compile(r'^Nvidia (\w+).+')
m = p.search(str(specs))
print(m) 

browser.quit()
```

How do I split up this response? I only want to print the content of the first `<li>` and without the HTML syntax.

```html
<ul class="specs"><li>Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 grafik</li><li>AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H processor</li><li>16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD</li></ul>
```

Comment: Looks like you're already using beautifulsoup to find the `ul`. Why not use that to find the `li` and its `innerHTML` also

Comment: ul.specs:first-child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `soup.select_one(".specs > li")`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<ul class="specs"><li>Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 grafik</li><li>AMD R
yzen™ 7 5800H processor</li><li>16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD</li></ul>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.select(".specs > li")
[<li>Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 grafik</li>, <li>AMD Ryzen™ 7 5800H processor</li>,
 <li>16 GB RAM, 1 TB SSD</li>]
>>> soup.select_one(".specs > li")
<li>Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 grafik</li>
>>> soup.select_one(".specs > li").text
'Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 grafik'
```

Since you're already using Selenium, you could use its CSS element selector in case the element is dynamic, or just to avoid the BeautifulSoup re-parse and dependency: `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".specs > li")`.